# Windows 10: Disable automatically encryption files on Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption

For the first time, I enabled the encryption for a file on Desktop manually. After enabling, Windows asked me 'Do you want to encrypt all files on Desktop automatically?' and I said YES!, and now, any modifications on desktop files make them encrypted and a padlock icon would be on them. I don't want to transparent that icon or anything, I just want to say NO to that question and disable this functionality.

Comment: How did you enable encryption?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming this encryption is handled by Windows BitLocker.

Microsoft provides a step-by-step guide.

> 1. Click Start > Control Panel > Security > BitLocker Drive Encryption
> 2. Find the volume on which you want BitLocker Drive Encryption turned
>      off, and click Turn Off BitLocker Drive Encryption.
> 3. From the "What level of decryption do you want" dialog box, click either
>      **Disable BitLocker Drive Encryption** or **Decrypt the volume**.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766295(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_S7

Comment: BitLocker is off for the drive.